# API de Gifs em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

é minha duvida e a seguinte eu tenho esse script onde eu digito o nome do gif que eu quero e ele me retorna vários tipo de url do tamanho(largura,altura) do gif sorteado aleatoriamente, eu queria que ele me retornasse apenas isso:

> image_url':
>   'https://media1.giphy.com/media/3og0IEvmsGQMvKRTEs/giphy.gif',
>   que no caso seria a maior imagem que ele tem.

Como faço isso?

> script  tirado :https://github.com/Giphy/giphy-python-client/blob/master/docs/DefaultApi.md#gifs_random_get

```
import time
import giphy_client
from giphy_client.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint


api_instance = giphy_client.DefaultApi()
api_key = 'dc6zaTOxFJmzC' 
tag = input('Nome do gif : ') 
rating = 'g' 
fmt = 'json' 

try: 
    # Random Endpoint
    api_response = api_instance.gifs_random_get(api_key, tag=tag, rating=rating, fmt=fmt)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling DefaultApi->gifs_random_get: %s\n" % e)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
...
pprint(api_response.data.image_url)
...
```

Comment: Funcionou Muito obrigado